# How to do eager loading when association is 2 levels deep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say my models are like:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chapters
end

class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  has_many :pages
end

class Pages < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chapter
end
```

I am currently doing this:

```
book = Book.find(1)

book.chapters.each do |chapter|
end
```

But now I need access to the chapter.pages inside of the loop, so I want to eager load all the pages for each chapter.

I know I can do this for chapters:

```
book = Book.includes(:chapters).find(1)
```

**But how to eager load the pages?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array to the name of the association:

```
Book.includes(chapters: [:pages])
```